# How to pass Function to a reusable Text Input widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I just refactor my code and make all my input widget as a separate widget as follows:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
class textInput extends StatelessWidget {
  const textInput({
    Key? key,
    required this.label,
    required this.inputController,
    required this.inputIcon,
    this.helperText,
    this.suffixHelpText,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String label;
  final TextEditingController inputController;
  final Icon inputIcon;
  final Widget? suffixHelpText;
  final String? helperText;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      controller: inputController,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: label,
        helperText: helperText != null ? helperText : '',
        icon: inputIcon,
        suffixIcon: suffixHelpText,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now I want to pass `OnChnaged` event to this widget which can be optional. I am trying as follows:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class textInput extends StatelessWidget {
  const textInput({
    Key? key,
    required this.label,
    required this.inputController,
    required this.inputIcon,
    this.helperText,
    this.suffixHelpText,
    this.onChangeEvent,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String label;
  final TextEditingController inputController;
  final Icon inputIcon;
  final Widget? suffixHelpText;
  final String? helperText;
  final Function? onChangeEvent;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      controller: inputController,
      onChanged: onChangeEvent !=null? onChangeEvent:(){},
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: label,
        helperText: helperText != null ? helperText : '',
        icon: inputIcon,
        suffixIcon: suffixHelpText,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But getting error with this  `onChanged: onChangeEvent !=null? onChangeEvent:(){},` line. Am I trying something which is not possible in deed? Or Is there any good approach? I love to clean my code in entire project. Please help.

Comment: `onChanged: onChangedEvent != null? (_) => onChangedEvent() : null`

Comment: or `onChanged: (_) => onChangedEvent?.call()`

Answer (score 2):

The `Function` expected in `onChanged` is `void Function(String)? onChanged`

Just change

```
final Function? onChangeEvent
```

as below:

```
final Function(String?)? onChangeEvent;
```

and just pass the `onChangeEvent` as below:

```
onChanged: onChangeEvent
```

Answer (score 0):

```
onChanged: onChangeEvent != null ? (_) => onChangeEvent!() : null,
```

works for me. Hope this will help other. Here is the full code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class textInput extends StatelessWidget {
  const textInput({
    Key? key,
    required this.label,
    required this.inputController,
    required this.inputIcon,
    this.helperText,
    this.suffixHelpText,
    this.onChangeEvent,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String label;
  final TextEditingController inputController;
  final Icon inputIcon;
  final Widget? suffixHelpText;
  final String? helperText;
  final Function? onChangeEvent;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      controller: inputController,
      onChanged: onChangeEvent != null ? (_) => onChangeEvent!() : null,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: label,
        helperText: helperText != null ? helperText : '',
        icon: inputIcon,
        suffixIcon: suffixHelpText,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```